# Is there a way to run st_split from within QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis

Is there a way to run st_split from within QGIS?  I am looking to split a polygon with a line feature.  My data is stored in a PostGIS database, and I would like to perform this operation from within QGIS.  I am aware of PG_Query for QGIS, but st_split is not a tool within the plugin.

Thanks...

Comment: only Vector>Data Management>Split Vector Layers but creates a shapfile can be imported into PostGIS with spit plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly access PostGIS in QGIS to issue the sql command as follows:

- add your db connection via Layer -- Add PostGIS Layer.
- under Database -- DB Manager. connect to database. open the SQL Window.
- issue the sql to split the line.

simple select statement to display in QGIS (click Load as Layer at bottom sql window):

`select row_number() over() as id, st_split(line.the_geom,polygon.the_geom) as the_geom from line,polygon`

create new table in postgis to hold:

`create table new_data as select row_number() over() as id, st_split(line.the_geom,polygon.the_geom) as the_geom from line,polygon`

[st_split page entry](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Split.html)